# How to change slider style of MediaPlayerElement on Xbox?

Tags: xaml, uwp, media-player

How to change the default style of 'MediaSliderStyle' of `MediaPlayerElement` on XBox?
I can custom some colors in MediaTransportControls.xaml, and remove the default focused green border.
But how to make the circle grow just grow 2x bigger, when focused on the whole slider.

Currently when focued on the slider as pic.1, I have to press GamePadA, and turn to pic.2, then to move timeline.

How to define the behavior like Android TV, exo player, to let user do less operation.

Pic.1 Focused.

[image]

Pic.2 Selected timeline to fast forward and rewind.

[image]

Pic.3 Android TV(Exo player) timeline unfocued.
[image]

Pic.4 Android TV(Exo player) timeline focued, press left/right to fast forward and rewind.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default `MediaTransportControls` style [here](https://github.com/msdnwptest/UWP-Support-Samples/tree/master/MediaTransportControlsDefaultStyle), which also includes the complete style code for the progress bar.

`MediaTransportControls` is composed of multiple controls. The progress bar is mainly composed of `Slider` and `Thumb`, but it does not expose states like `ThumbFocus`, only regular states such as `PointerOver`, `Pressed`, etc.

In the default code, we can change the size of the thumb by modifying the Width / Height of the `HorizontalThumb`:

```xml
...
<!-- Default width / height are 24 -->
<Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
       Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
       Height="10"
       Width="10"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.RowSpan="3"
       Grid.Column="1"
       FocusVisualMargin="-14,-6,-14,-6"
       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
...
```

Then change the size of the thumb in `PointerOver` state and `Pressed` state:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="24" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="24" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        ...
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

It works well in keyboard and mouse mode, but it won't take effect if the control is selected by switching focus.

If this effect is important, you may need to rewrite the `Slider` and create events when focus is acquired.

Best regards.

Comment: OK, it seems ms does not want to do ui change to adapt to TV devices currently. We have to override all the UI. Do you know where to report this feature to MS, excepting Feedback Hub.

Comment: If it's a Feature Request, it is recommended to submit it in the `Feedback Hub`. This will help your problem get more attention.